# Own spline calculation within highcharts possible?

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way in Highcharts to add an own spline calculation or do I have to caluclation several points and add that to the regular spline calculation as values?

Answer (score 0):

You have to first calculate your points, then add them to the chart.